# Could not find method compile() on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, axelor, gradle-wrapper

I'm trying to install [Axelor ERP](https://axelor.com/) opensource project as indicated in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gX0RPREPok), but after trying to build first time with the provided command:

```
gradlew clean classes build -x test cleanEclipse eclipse
```

I got:

```
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
```

Looks googling like a problem with gradle version:

```
Build time:   2019-11-01 20:42:00 UTC
Revision:     dd870424f9bd8e195d614dc14bb140f43c22da98

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
```

This is what I have in my machine:

```
JVM:          13.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 13.0.1+9)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Then I downloaded and installed latest gradle version, and now I have:

```
Gradle 7.4.1
Build time:   2022-03-09 15:04:47 UTC
Revision:     36dc52588e09b4b72f2010bc07599e0ee0434e2e
Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
```

But after run again the build command:

```
gradlew clean classes build -x test cleanEclipse eclipse
```

I got this:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':modules:axelor-bpm'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.camunda.bpm:camunda-engine:7.16.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Then, I went to modules:axelor-bpm and found this gradle build file

```
apply plugin: "com.axelor.app-module"

apply from: "../libs.gradle"
apply from: "../version.gradle"

apply {
        version = openSuiteVersion
}

axelor {
        title "Axelor BPM"
        description "Axelor BPM  Module"
}

test {
    exclude "com/axelor/apps/baml/test/**"
}


dependencies {
  compile ("org.camunda.bpm:camunda-engine:7.16.0")
  compile ("org.camunda.bpm:camunda-engine-plugin-spin:7.16.0")
  compile ("org.camunda.spin:camunda-spin-dataformat-json-jackson:1.10.1")
  api project(":modules:axelor-studio")
}
```

I have also googled it and in other stackoverflows help request, people report that the problem maybe was related to a missing line break in compile lines, however, it's not the case.

Also I tried to update the wrapper with this:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version=7.4.1 --distribution-type=bin
```

but I got same `Could not find method compile() for arguments...` error, saying that the problem is the build file.

Any other suggestion? Thank you so much.

Comment: Haven't looked at the video, but `Unsupported class file major version 57` doesn't mean it is the wrong version of Gradle - rather, it means you are building with an incompatible version of Java. From the looks of it, you need Java 8 instead of Java 13. Also, even if it were Gradle, you usually can't just bump two major versions (5.6 to 7.4) without any changes.

Comment: I'll try to fix it with your suggestions, and I'll update it soon.